# Check if a child is React.Fragment

Tags: reactjs, react-fragment

As I see `React.isFragment` is only a proposal for the moment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12038

Is there a workaround to do something like

```
if (child instanceof React.Fragment) {
  ...
}
```

until that API is available.

Temporary solution that works for me:

```
const isReactFragment = child => {
  try {
    return child.type.toString() === React.Fragment.toString();
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not available? According to this comment you can try out the package (though an alpha version) already: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12038#issuecomment-365023560

Comment: @Niekert You are right, it should be available through `react-is` package, which is alpha right now.

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays, this is possible:

```
function isReactFragment(variableToInspect) {
  if (variableToInspect.type) {
    return variableToInspect.type === React.Fragment;
  }
  return variableToInspect === React.Fragment;
}
```

The check for `variableToInspect.type` is because component *instances* have that property.

Answer (score 15):

For completeness sake the package [`react-is`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is) is now the recommended way to go as mentioned in the closing message of the above issue.

Use like this:

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactIs from 'react-is';

ReactIs.isFragment(<></>); // true
ReactIs.typeOf(<></>) === ReactIs.Fragment; // true
```